# Make $\pi = 3$ again

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, curvature

The value of $\pi$, or the circumference divided by the diameter of a circle, is known with absurd precision, but I want it to be 3.

The circumference around a black hole outside the Schwarzschild radius is knowable. From the stationary frame outside of that radius, so is the diameter, but it is clear that we cannot traverse that diameter - in essence, it is infinite from the perspective of a traveler. In this instance, $\pi = 0$.

Can we do something like a line integral in GR to find the traversal diameter of a constant density sphere? If so, can we solve for the mass, $M$, and radius where $\pi' = 3$, $r_{3}$, in terms of normal things like density, $\rho$, and other universal constants? For the solution, assume that an instance of $\pi$ has the Euclidean value. The solution radius may be inside or outside the sphere.

In response to the comments, [a 2D demonstration](https://physics.illinois.edu/news/article/10665).

Comment: How about $3.2$ instead [Indiana Pi Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill), [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFNjA9LOPsg)

Comment: $\pi$ is a dimensionless ratio of circumference to diameter.  It is what it is, and it cannot be arbitrarily redefined.

Comment: GR alone is not enough, since locally is (almost) always flat, so you have locally 3.14...  we have to find a funny metric/fractal space

Comment: @DavidWhite $\pi$ IS a dimensionless ratio of circumference to diameter. In euclidean space it has a well described value. Sadly, we don't live there, and I'm not asking about that.

Comment: @MannyC The curvature of space would have to go the other way.

Comment: What happened to old good 22/7 ? :-)

Comment: Why the word "again" in the title?

Comment: Great catchphrase, I mean, title.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I think it's because the question is different from the what physicists are used to seeing and perhaps too difficult.

Comment: I think it's much more important that we work on making the square root of 2 rational.

Comment: Make physics rational again. The naysayers are apparently the 'irrational' bunch.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a π in a general relativity equation it is still the good old π. Ιn general relativity we do not use a different π, instead we say the circumference is no longer 2πr.

Comment: Clearly, you did not read the question or chose to ignore its contents.

Comment: I gave the best answer I had, if you have a better one feel free to write your own

Comment: I get it. Reading is hard.